# What's the correct way to reassign keys with xkb?

Tags: xkb

I have an Apple keyboard with a Swedish layout and this makes some characters very awkward to type, like right Alt key and 7 to type a left brace. Therefor I would like to reassign the right Command key to have the same function as the right Alt key. What is the correct way to achieve this with `xkb`?

My current solution is to load a modified dump from `xkbcomp` where I have swapped the keycodes for `RWIN` and `RALT` but this feels like a hack. Is anyone experienced with `xkb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This neat command solves the problem:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:rwin_switch
```

Comment: @Sparhawk: OK, done. Easy to forget when you have to wait x hours before you are allowed to accept your own answer.

Comment: Have some rep :)

Comment: What does the lv3 mean? I want to accomplish the same thing except switching the menu insteaf of the rwim. I replaced rwin_ with menu_ and now the menu key behaves as I want but not the left Alt(GR)